# Use Google Drive for live DB backup?

Tags: backup, database, google-drive

I am currently trying to define my backup strategy for my AWS EC2 server. I already use Google Drive to backup my apache root folder. This also automatically doubles as a deployment strategy since the drive folder is linked to my local repo on my home PC.

I was wondering if I could also include the database data directory and have it synced with Google Drive? Or should I rather stick with conventional SQL dumps for backup?

Comment: Why not use Amazon S3 or Glacier for your backups?

Comment: "This also automatically doubles as a deployment strategy since the drive folder is linked to my local repo on my home PC." I'm not sure I'd call that a "deployment strategy" for anything important.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok, let's rather say, Changes to my website will be automatically affect the website hosted on the server

Comment: @joeqwerty It could be anything like OneDrive, GDrive, Dropbox, etc. I am just not aware of a live sync option for S3. (i.e. software that runs on the server and constantly checks for file changes)

Comment: @Chris I'm saying any sort of "automatically live sync local to production" is a bad idea for anything important. Typically you'd want some sort of CI in between and a proper deployment process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big, constantly changing files as the one backing relational databases are **not** good candidate for this kind of continuous backup. I strongly advise you to dump your databases (with the relevant utility) and *then* to upload the dumps on Google Drive.

Also, pay attention that Google Drive does **not** automatically empty the trash folder. This means that if you rotate your local dumps, deleting the old ones, they will continue to use space on your Google Drive account (in the Trash). So you will need to periodically empty your Trash folder, in a manual or programmatical manner.

Comment: I do not really know how DBs save to the file system, but my data folder (PostgreSQL) contains lots of small chunks (few KB), rather than one big file. I assumed that only few of those small parts change during transactions

Comment: Sure, but these files are **constantly** changing. Moreover, as your database grows, these files grow with it.